# How to specify/change git merge strategy in E Git plugin

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, git-merge, egit

We want to change the default merge strategy provided by E Git.From git scm reference it is specified that merge strategy can be given by -X. Can it be done from eclipse as well??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

Egit has an extension point to provide different merge strategies (than the default one given by the jgit implementation), but that extension point is merely meant to provide higher level semantic aware merge implementations, e.g. for merging UML diagrams in the Papyrus plugins.

You can only change the default of the merge tool content (last HEAD, workspace pre-merged, or prompt) in the git workspace preferences.